# Trying to connect to Thrift server for Hbase. Getting the following error

Tags: python, hbase, thrift, happybase

To use Happybase - Python, we need to get our Thrift server up and running for Hbase as mentioned in the Happybase docs.

I'm getting the following java runtime exception while kick starting the Thrift server for Happybase.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.sink.timeline.HadoopTimelineMetricsSink.init(Lorg/apache/phoenix/shaded/org/apache/commons/configuration/SubsetConfiguration;

I'm using the following command to start the Thrift server..

```
hbase thrift start
```

Comment: Not sure, but IIRC there are two different Thrift APIs at Hbase ... or do I just mix up things?

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
```

Use jps then to see if the Thrift process is running. Works for us...

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. It is giving me the bind exception saying - it is already running on the port. If i change the port, it gives me the same error with the new port i mentioned.

Comment: Ah if it's already running then not sure how to help. Have you tried connecting to it from Python? Make sure to specify that port; the default seems to be 9095